# How to interactive command in expect script

Tags: bash, expect

I have a small expect script, and I want to send command based on output.
this is example

```
#! /usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh root@hostname
expect "Password:"
send "12345\r"
expect "root@host:#"
send "ls -lrt"  # depend on this output I need delete file
```

from here, if i have file list a,b,c,d
I want to send "rm a" but file name will change each time when I run script.
I don't know how script make wait until I put command, also I don't want to type rm command every time. I only want to type file name.(this is example, the real command is long, I don't want to type same long command every time.)
So what I want is that the script wait until I put only file name and after I type file name, it send "rm filename" and keep going rest of script.

please help..

Comment: #! /usr/bin/expect

Comment: It looks like you are going a wrong way. You use an expect script to get a lite of remote files, then you want to decide which one should be deleted and then you will input the name in order to get it deleted? BTW - never ever write passwords in clear text into a script or a program.

Comment: hi Thanks for command. This script for delete certain file when I run, that is depend on output. I have 10 machine need do same action. so what is a good way to achieve this goal ?

Comment: Why use expect at all? Why not setup key authentification and do something like `ssh root@hostname ls -lrt`

Comment: "so what is a good way to achieve this goal ?" - just tell the rule how to decide which file must be deleted and then you will have the chance to get an simple answer which will surely not use expect. (I love expect and I use it but here it is surely wrong.)

Comment: @han : After executing the `ls -lrt` command, do you have to delete all the files  Or just a few depends on your requirement and which is what you want to get it from you ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `expect_user`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh root@hostname
expect "Password:"
send "12345\r"
expect "root@host:#"
send "ls -lrt"  # depend on this output I need delete file

expect_user -re "(.*)\n" {
    set filename $expect_out(1,string)
    send "ls -al $filename\r"    ;#// Substitute with desired command
}

expect eof
```

Answer (score -1):

this does not need to be interactive at all. I assume your requirement is to delete the *oldest* file. so do this:

```
ssh root@hostname 'stat -c "%Y:%n" * | sort -t: -k1,1n | head -1 | cut -d: -f2- | xargs echo rm'
# .. remove the "echo" if you're satisfied it finds the right file .................... ^^^^
```